# how to write condition for when I send same movie name in postman i will not accept for same movienames

Tags: java, json, playframework-2.5

This is movie class

. I have code for add the movie in postman using post request.

```
public class Movie {


    private int id;
    private String movieName;
    private String description;
    private String hero;
    private String heroine;

    public Movie(){

    }

    public Movie(int id, String movieName, String description, String hero, String heroine) {
        this.id = id;
        this.movieName = movieName;
        this.description = description;
        this.hero = hero;
        this.heroine = heroine;

    }
//here have setter and getter methods
```

This is controller class.now what the logic for not accept duplicate moviename

```
public class MovieController extends Controller {

    public static List<Movie> movies;

    static {
        movies = new ArrayList<>();
        movies.add(new Movie(1, "Fprd vs Ferrari", "Movie on Racing", "abcd", "xyz"));
        movies.add(new Movie(2, "F2", "Comedy Movie", "Venkatesh", "Tamanna"));
        movies.add(new Movie(3, "Titanic", "Movie", "Hero", "Heroine"));
        movies.add(new Movie(4, "Saaho", "action", "Prabhas", "Shradda kapoor"));
        movies.add(new Movie(5, "Bhahubali 1", "action", "Prabhas", "Tamanna"));

    }
 public Result insert(Http.Request request) {
        JsonNode jsonNode = request.body().asJson();
        if (jsonNode == null) {
            return badRequest("insufficient movie information");
        }
        Movie movie = Json.fromJson(jsonNode, Movie.class);
        movies.add(movie);
        return ok(Json.toJson(movie));
    }
```

This is the Routing for post request

```
POST        /newmovies              controllers.MovieController.insert(request: Request)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Movie movie = Json.fromJson(jsonNode, Movie.class);

if(movies.stream().noneMatch(m -> m.getMovieName().equals(movie.getName()))) {
    movies.add(movie);
    return ok(Json.toJson(movie));
} else {
    // Movie name already exists... Throw exception here
    return badRequest("Movie already exists");
}
```

Comment: can you help? i have one more doubt

Comment: Yes, sure. How can I help?

Comment: now I give id using pots request in postman body.  But now I want to auto increment of id when I add movie and  I have static movie list id No:5 now, Its start increment with id no 6 onwards(once refer above code i think you can understand sir) So how can I write logic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205410/discussion-between-k-neha-and-mushif-ali-nawaz).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve this problem is to override the equals method on Movie object.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
if (obj == this) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    Movie movie= (Movie) obj;
    return movie.getMovieName().equals(this.movieName);
}
```

Here you can define your logic for checking the equality of two movies(Movie name comparison).
This approach will be more maintainable

And then simply check whether the list contains the movie in request using

```
    if (movies.contains(movie)) {
      return badRequest("Movie already exists");
    } 
    movies.add(movie);
    return ok(Json.toJson(movie));
```

Comment: .equals(movieName) here it will show error is declare local variable

Comment: return movie.getMovieName().equals(this.movieName);

You are overriding equals in Movie class, right?
I could see the variable movieName in Movie class (this.movieName)